# error occurs when getting data from webservice with apache.cxf dynamic client

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, webservice-client

#### I write a cxf dynamic client to get data from wsdl url, belowing is my client:

```
public static String invoke(String wsdlUrl, String operationName, Object inputParams) {
    try {
        JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
        Client client = dcf.createClient(wsdlUrl);
        Object[] result = client.invoke(operationName, inputParams);

        return (String) result[0];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### webservice document says the service should receive a param with xml-form string like:

```
<startDate>2023-11-10</startDate>
<endDate>2023-11-01</endDate>
<accessID>XXXX</accessID>
<accessPasswords>XXXXX</accessPasswords>
<customID>1</customID>
```

#### params when i invoke the service like belowing:

```
String salesResult = WebServiceClient.invoke(url, salesOperation, paramForSales);
```

url: http://59.41.111.229:9000/vendorService?wsdl

salesOperation: getSaleInfo

paramForSales: String like this

```
<startDate>2023-11-10</startDate><endDate>2023-11-01</endDate><accessID>XXXX</accessID><accessPasswords>XXXXX</accessPasswords><customID>1</customID>
```

#### an error occurs like:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:316)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.oval.ddi.ws.ws_client.WebServiceClient.invoke(WebServiceClient.java:22)
    at org.oval.ddi.ws.data.GuoKongGuangZhouFetcher.execute(GuoKongGuangZhouFetcher.java:70)
    at org.oval.ddi.ws.process.GuoKongGuangZhouConcreteProcess.execute(GuoKongGuangZhouConcreteProcess.java:30)
    at org.oval.ddi.ws.WebServiceBootStrap.main(WebServiceBootStrap.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.sinopharm_gz.vendorddi.GetSaleInfo_WrapperTypeHelper1.createWrapperObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:91)
    ... 11 more
```

this webservice should **return a xml-formed string**, but null returned actually.

btw, where should i revise to make my webservice client **more universal for all webservice?**

im a java new learner, if you need more information of this problem, please **ask me directly**.

**sincerely thanks to all developers' time!**